# Stuck on assigning parts of an array to a number in Verilog

Tags: arrays, verilog, quartus

```
input [31:0] instruction;
output [4:0] read_reg_1;

read_reg_1 <= instruction[6:10];
```

I want to assign array elements 6 to 10(6-7-8-9-10) as 5 bit numbers of `read_reg_1`

```
Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at mips_fetch.v(8) near text "<=";  expecting ".", or "("
```

This is the error I get during operation. It seems it should work though I can't find solution or problem to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you define `read_reg_1` without a type, your compiler by default assumes it's a `wire`, not a `reg` so you can't assign to it with `<=`.

Either do this:

```
input wire [31:0] instruction;
output reg [4:0]  read_reg_1;

always @*
    read_reg_1 = instruction[6:10];
```

Or this:

```
input  wire [31:0] instruction;
output wire [4:0]  read_reg_1;

assign read_reg_1 = instruction[6:10];
```

Or this:

```
input wire [31:0] instruction;
output reg [4:0]  read_reg_1;

always @(posedge clk)
    read_reg_1 <= instruction[6:10];
```